# query focused display info from command line

Tags: terminal, display, resolution

Is it possible to query the properties of the currently focused monitor (dpi/resolution)?

The goal is to configure a shortcut (with `skhd`) to spawn my terminal (`alacritty`) with a different font size depending on the display I'm working in.